# Code below One Line 'If Statement' following condition of If Statement.C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have noticed on several occasions that I may be creating a problem (described below) when I lay my C++ code out as below.  While it may not be ideal, I do it to save space sometimes.

I can only show you a small code snipped because the program is quiet large.  Hopefully can articulate the problem clearly.

```
    string st= "TestString,"; // I declare a string.
    //further down in my code I want to remove the comma as I do below.
    // I do it in the below syntax to save space.  Ok, maybe not ideal but I did it.

    if(st[st.length()-1]==','){st=st.substr(0,st.length()-1);}
    cout << "My new string is: " << st << endl; 

 // I place a line of codeimmediately below my if statement.
```

The problem is, sometimes the code directly below my one line If Statement follows the logic of the If Statement when I thought that would be reserved for the code only int the { } .

It doesn't always happen but it does happen randomly.  When I leave a space between the One Line If Statement and the code below it, the problem goes away.

Is there a common problem I have created here or is this just an unusual anomaly?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why not refactor the code into its own function if its so frequently used?

Comment: Why do you need to save space? Doing so makes the code unreadable

Comment: @domonica  As for me then I have understood nothing.:)

Comment: The purpose of the question is to ascertain whether this would normally cause a problem (the way I have laid it out).  Is it known?  Is it common?  I could refactor the code and I could create a function, but in this case I haven't.  It's simply to cram some code into a small space for reasons I can't go into.

Comment: I do not see any problem removing some of the comments/spaces. But why?

Comment: C++ completely ignores whitespace. If moving the statement around changes the behaviour of the program, then your compiler is broken.

Comment: It could be what you're saying.:                                         if(st[st.length()-1]==','){st=st.substr(0,st.length()-1);}
cout << "My new string is: " << st << endl;     this line of code right below the "If" could be read as part of the "If" logic, which as Quentin said, could be a compiler issue.    Good question though because stranger things have happened and it could help someone else.

Comment: Do you see any benefit in making statements fit on one line?  Compiler's don't care.  In most coding standards, the `if` statements are rarely on one line due to readability and maintenance issues.  If a program is easier to read, it usually has less defects.

Comment: You may be a good candidate to participate in the [International Obfuscated C Code Contest](http://www.ioccc.org/)

Comment: "When I leave a space between the One Line If Statement and the code below it, the problem goes away." <-- use the one that works. Since we are not writing in machine language or the legacy C, we could save a lot of compiler compatibility issues. (: